# Comparison between Nusah Sfard (Ashkenazi) and Nusah Ashkenaz for regular days as well as Shabat

Tags: tefilla, minhag, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

I would like to know if there is any source (such as table) that summarizes the differences along the Tefila in the Nusah Sfard (Ashkenazi) and Nusah Ashkenaz for regular days as well as Shabat?

Comment: i’ll summarize bli neder after yom tov